# CFAJAXPROXY is putting script into the head tag, not between the open and close head tags

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

We are using ColdFusion 8.

We are using CFAJAXPROXY. We just discovered that the  tag that ColdFusion inserts in the head tag has an issue.  It works fine on page that have a head tag like this:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

But, it does NOT work on pages where there is an ID in the head tag, like this:

```
<head id="SomeID">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

What happens is that CFJAXPROXY inserts the script inside the head tag, not withing the open and close head tags, which blows up the page, like this:

```
<head <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

The problem goes away immediately if the ID is removed from the head tag.

The question is whether this is a known CFAJAXPROXY bug? Is there a way to tell CFAJAXPROXY put the script within the head area but not in the head tag?

Comment: Tagging with `coldfusion-9` as it happens there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you inserting the `<cfajaxproxy>` into the page? Are you using a `<cfinclude>`, custom tag, or perhaps a method in Application.cfc? Anyway, a couple of things come to mind. If you're just putting the `<cfajaxproxy>` into an include file that already exists (i.e.:

```
<html>
<cfinclude template="stuff.cfm" />
<head id="head1">
</head>
...
```

), then perhaps you can insert a new `<head>` tag (without the `id=`) above the current one. I've tested and it works as far as `<cfajaxproxy>` is concerned, though I don't know what side effects it might have. It **won't** work if you put another `<head>` tag below the current one, or if you try to nest them or anything like that. What CF appears to be doing is looking for the first occurrence of `<head`, advancing one character, and then inserting the JS code. Another approach might be to use a phony tag including `<head` (this "works" as well):

```
<fake<head>
</fake<head>
```

Of course, that tag is not legitimate XML so that could screw things up if you're parsing your templates using XMLParse() or anything like that.

**UPDATE:** Here's another method you can use, which may work. I tried it but don't know if it will work with complex code. You would do the following in the `onRequest()` method of Application.cfc. I don't know what it would do to your processing time though:

```
<cffunction name="onRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true">
    <cfargument name="target_page" type="string" required="true" />

    ...

    <cfsilent>
    <!--- Grab the requested page. --->
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.target_page">
        <cfinclude template="#arguments.target_page#" />
    </cfsavecontent>

    <!--- Replace bad <head> tag with good one --->
    <cfset local.target_page = REReplace(local.target_page, "(<head[^>]*>)", "<head>") />
    <cfajaxproxy ... />
    </cfsilent>
    <cfoutput>#local.target_page#</cfoutput>

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: David, you said: "What CF appears to be doing is looking for the first occurrence of <head, advancing one character, and then inserting the JS code."  This is exactly what I deduced.  Your solution "<fake<head></fake<head>" is interesting. I'll give it a try.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @EvikJames, I hope it works. If not I came up with a solution that uses `onRequest()` (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you should be adding an ID to the head tag.  That's not proper HTML syntax.

Comment: I agree. We have 1,000+ sites though and we really can't change them without some real time investment. This is obviously something that ColdFusion is doing wrong. I am looking for a ColdFusion solution first, before we start fixing the sites.

Comment: @EvikJames, I don't think ColdFusion is doing anything wrong, it is doing something inconvenient.

Comment: html 5 has id as a global attribute, so it can be added to the HEAD tag.  If its not an HTML 5 doctype then it shouldn't be there.  That said, it does look like ColdFusion is incorrectly parsing the HEAD tag, because of the id attribute.  It doesn't look like there is a bug reported for it, so I would suggest posting one : https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: @EvikJames, I take back what I said earlier. It is a bug, it doesn't even work properly when you use `<head >` instead of `<head>`. That was what clued me in to the fact that CF is just looking for `<head`, advancing one character (no matter what that character is), and inserting the code. It affects `<head>` tags with the `id` attribute, but that is not the underlying cause of the issue.

Comment: @StephenMoretti, I reported the bug today: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3146932

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem with a Facebook App, where there needs to be a "prefix" attribute on the HEAD tag.

Before CFAJAXPROXY I used a third party solution called CFAjax for my AJAX calls.

http://www.indiankey.com/cfajax/

**UPDATED**

I ran a test in ColdFusion 10 using <head id="test" prefix="test">.

ColdFusion injected the script tags after the closing '>' of the HEAD tag. So this is clearly a bug with CF8 and CF9.

Comment: Maybe that got fixed in ColdFusion 10, but I doubt it.

Comment: I have CF 10 installed on a dev box at home. I may try this later tonight just to see what happens. I'll post my findings.

Comment: CFAJAXPROXY works in version 10 even if the HEAD tag has additional parameters

Comment: Yet another great reason to spend $10k+ to upgrade!